# Updating meta tags not working(View Page Source) in Angular6

Tags: angular, meta-tags, angular6, angular-universal

We built a website using Angular 6 Universal App, Meta tags are not Updating in the View Page Source. (https://therightdoctors.com/one-more-thing/dr-s-ramakrishnan-additional-professor-cad-stroke-and-renal-diseases-are-on-a-scale-that-is-unbelievable)

Please Check The Code Below

```
this.titleService.setTitle('Dr.S Ramakrishnan | TheRightDoctors');

this.meta.updateTag({name: 'description', content:'TheRightDoctors  Dr.S Ramakrishnan After discharge of a STEMI patient… story continues'});

this.meta.updateTag({name: 'keywords', content:'dr s ramakrishnan,dr s ramakrishnan iit madras,Cardiologist, TheRightDoctors, TheRightDoctors.com, the right doctors,Dr. S RamaKrishnan, Dept. of Cardiology, AIIMS, New Delhi'});

            this.meta.updateTag({
              property: 'vr:canonical',
              content: 'https://therightdoctors.com/one-more-thing/dr-s-ramakrishnan-additional-professor-cad-stroke-and-renal-diseases-are-on-a-scale-that-is-unbelievable'
            });
```

Same tags are displaying in Inspect Element. please check below image

[image]

Comment: Check if you don't have errors server side while rendering. That's usually the cause

Comment: I checked errors while rendering server side. There are no errors found, still, it is not working...

Comment: What can you see when you view the source exactly?

Comment: In view page Source meta tags are not updating, it is displaying whatever it is there in index.html (Please check this URL - https://therightdoctors.com/one-more-thing/dr-s-ramakrishnan-additional-professor-cad-stroke-and-renal-diseases-are-on-a-scale-that-is-unbelievable)

Comment: If we will change Route for this URL (https://therightdoctors.com/one-more-thing/dr-s-ramakrishnan-additional-professor-cad-stroke-and-renal-diseases-are-on-a-scale-that-is-unbelievable) to (https://therightdoctors.com/all/one-more-thing/dr-s-ramakrishnan-additional-professor-cad-stroke-and-renal-diseases-are-on-a-scale-that-is-unbelievable) then it is working.. Problem here is i can't change the route(url). please suggest some solution...

Comment: @therightdoctors, did you find any solution, same issue in my case

Comment: @therightdoctors Hey did u find any solution. I am also getting the same issue. Can u help me out what u have done

Comment: Good question - and still looking for an answer! I came across this while looking for solution for an Angular 11 Universal application. In developer tools I can see that the meta tags are updated as expected, but not in initial render (ie when viewing page source). It's the page source that the social media platforms will inspect, so it's not a solution to update meta tags after initial render.